# compare each array element with each list element in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, data-structures

I have a numpy array `x =np.array([2,1,0,18, 7, 4, 9])`  and a list `y=[0, 3, 4]`.

For each element in the array I want to check if it is in the list.

For this, I will normally do:
`(x == y[0]) | (x == y[1]) | (x == y[2])`,  (Equation 1)

which will give me what I want.

Now suppose that Equation (1) lies inside a function which take `x,y` as input.

My problem is that `y` can have variable length so, I need a way to automate equation (1), (independant of the length of `y`).
Thanks.

Comment: You may use `numpy.in1d(x, y)`.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactely what I was looking for